# How to order a SiteCollection by Name

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to order a  Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteCollection by Name like that :

```
ServerManager iisManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(Vm.CurrentServeur);
SiteCollection websites = iisManager.Sites.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

But i get the following error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable ' to 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteCollection'

How can I order a SiteCollection ?

Comment: Do you need the `SiteCollection` at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  What can I use instead ?

Comment: Look at the answers, with `ToList` you create a list with `ToArray` and array and finally you can also use the `IEnumerable<Site>` directly which is returned from your LINQ query. But that would always execute the query(the ordering) if you would access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`SiteCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitecollection(v=vs.90).aspx) has no constructor you can't create it. You could use it's methods `Clear` and `Add`.

```
SiteCollection websites = iisManager.Sites;
List<Site> orderedSites = websites.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
websites.Clear();
foreach(Site s in orderedSites)
    websites.Add(s);
```

This modifies the original `SiteCollection`. If you don't need it at all you could use the `IEnumerable<Site>` or use the list directly:

```
List<Site> webSites = iisManager.Sites.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList<Site>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add `ToList`

```
iisManager.Sites.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: You might need to change the type of the list as so: `iisManager.Sites.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList<Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site>();`